# giving optional argument using filter method angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am implementing a filter tokenize that can take an optional argument for the delimiter.

By default, the filter produces a comma separated string of the individual characters of the given input. If the delimiter is provided, the individual characters in the input string are separated by the specified delimiter.

No token provided: (tokenize resolves to a comma):

```
{{"hello world"|tokenize}}
```

Results in:

```
h,e,l,l,o,,w,o,r,l,d
```

Token Provided:

```
{{"hello world"|tokenize:'#'}}
```

Results in:

```
h#e#l#l#o##w#o#r#l#d.
```

The problem is I am not able to pass optional argument and receive it to separate the string on the basis of optional delimiter.

Code for html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
   <head>
      <script src="angular.js"></script>
      <script src="filter.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div ng-controller='HelloController'>
         <label>Input</label><input ng-model='greeting'><br><br>
         <label>Delimeter</label><input ng-model='delimeter'><br>
         <p>{{greeting | tokenize}}(default)</p>
         <p>{{greeting| tokenize:arg1}}(with Option)</p>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

and my filter.js code is:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('HelloController', function($scope) {
        $scope.greeting = "Angular is Awesome";
        //$scope.delimeter="#";
    })
    .filter('tokenize', function() {
        return function(value) {
            if (angular.isString(value)) {
                var abc = [];
                abc = value.split('');
                value = abc.join();
                return value;
            } else {
                return value;
            }
        };    
    });
```

Comment: look at @emed answer below. "declare another param in your filter function". After that, split on the optional param or on ''.

Comment: ok what if i have to return two values one with default delimiter and other which comes with optional argument . How can that be done.

Comment: like i have to give two outputs:  h,e,l,l,o,,w,o,r,l,d (default)  and the other one h#e#l#l#o##w#o#r#l#d.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just declare another parameter in your filter function:

```
<p>{{"Angular is Awesome" | tokenize:'arg1'}}(with Option)</p>
                                     ^ Dont forget quotes if it isn't a variable


.filter('tokenize', function () {
    return function (value, optionalArg) {
        console.log(value); // Angular is Awesome
        console.log(optionalArg); // arg1

        if (angular.isString(value)) {
            var abc = [];
            abc = value.split('');
            value = abc.join(optionalArg); //pass the separator to join
            return value;
        } else {
            return value;
        }
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

Comment: A,n,g,u,l,a,r, ,i,s, ,A,w,e,s,o,m,e(default)

A,n,g,u,l,a,r, ,i,s, ,A,w,e,s,o,m,e(with Option) is the return i get . how do i return the option by applying arg1. so it means how to return two different values from function to                                                                             <div ng-controller='HelloController'>
    <label>Input</label><input ng-model='greeting'><br><br>
    <label>Delimeter</label><input ng-model='greeting'><br>
    <p>{{greeting | tokenize}}(default)</p>
    <p>{{greeting| tokenize:'arg1'}}(with Option)</p>
  </div>

Comment: @Rahila pass the separator to the join function, edited to show that part